# asp.net mvc3 updated (refresh) the viewmodel in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I send a BOOKVIEWMODEL with fields and a simple IEnumerable in view I get the this list IEnumerable in the view by a method with JSON AJAX in view and I fill my table Ristourne(View) with JQUERY it works very well but I not know how I fill (BIND or refresh) the list IEnumerable of my BOOKVIEWMODEL in the VIEW to recovered it in the Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(BookViewModel _bookViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        _bookViewModel.Ristourne



            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        return View(_bookViewModel);
```

my bookviewmodel

```
public class BookViewModel
    {

        public String book { get; set; }
        public String price { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Ristourne> Ristourne { get; set; }

        }
```

Comment: Make sure your form elements are written out into your html when rendering with the correct full name i.e. Ristourne[0].<name> etc  Other than that more info with your view code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

For the model binding to work, you need to "mimic" the  convention MVC uses when generating the form fields.

I don't know the contents of the `Ristourne` class, but let's say it had 1 field called `Foo`.

In that case, when you render out the elements (from the JSON AJAX callback), make them look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Model.Ristourne[0].Foo" id="Model.Ristourne[0].Foo"/>
<input type="text" name="Model.Ristourne[1].Foo" id="Model.Ristourne[1].Foo"/>
<input type="text" name="Model.Ristourne[2].Foo" id="Model.Ristourne[2].Foo"/>
```

And so on. Easiest thing to do is in your AJAX callback, just use a basic for loop to create the elements indexer.

**Altenatively,** a cheat/easy way around this problem would be to make your AJAX action return a `PartialViewResult`:

```
public PartialViewResult Book()
{
   var ristournes = _repo.Get();
   var model = new BooksViewModel { Ristourne = ristournes };
   return PartialView(model);
}
```

Then the partial view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => mode.Ristourne)
```

Then MVC will create the form fields correctly.

I always prefer this option over dynamically generated form fields. If you want to go down this path often, you should consider something like Knockout.js and/or Upshot.

Comment: The second option isvery well but if I understood I create a partialview book before ? because I have an exception it can not find partialview book